# How to make this loop 10 times then end

Tags: java

Creating a program that will ask 10 problems based on what problem type is selected. How do I make this ask only 10 times and display whether its wrong or right after each question?

I tried using for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) but it doesn't display if the answer is right or wrong after each one

```
{
    int userType, probType, level, op1=0, op2=0, correctAnswer, studentAnswer=0, numCorrect=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean playAgain;

    System.out.println("Problem Type 1 is sum, 2 is difference, 3 is product, 4 is quotient, and 5 is random. What problem type do you want?");
    probType = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You selected " + probType + ". What level from 1 to 3 do you want to play? ");
    level = input.nextInt();
    while(probType == 1){
        op1 = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
        op2 = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
    System.out.println("What is " + op1 + "+" + op2 + "?");
        studentAnswer = input.nextInt();
        }if(studentAnswer == op1 + op2){
            System.out.println(studentAnswer + " is correct");
            numCorrect++;
        }else{
            System.out.println(studentAnswer + " is wrong. The right answer is " + (op1 + op2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're having issues controlling your looping structures, you need to seriously simplify the body of your program.  Get it to the base basics (Loop, output statement, and variable increment) and get a firm understanding of how its working

Comment: I suggest you formatting your code in a more readable way. This way you will help us help you and also you will be able to see the code structure easier. See the answers below for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I have added static variable that is the number of questions you want the user to be asked (final int NUM_PROBLEMS = 10).

Your while loop was ending before the if statements. I have moved the while loop's closing bracket to the end, changed the while loop header to make sure the while loop stops when there has been 10 questions asked and at the bottom incremented problemCount every time a question has been asked.

```
{
        int userType, probType, level, op1=0, op2=0, correctAnswer, studentAnswer=0, numCorrect=0, problemCount=1;
        final int NUM_PROBLEMS = 10;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean playAgain;

        System.out.println("Problem Type 1 is sum, 2 is difference, 3 is product, 4 is quotient, and 5 is random. What problem type do you want?");
        probType = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You selected " + probType + ". What level from 1 to 3 do you want to play? ");
        level = input.nextInt();

        while(probType == 1 && problemCount <= NUM_PROBLEMS){
            op1 = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
            op2 = (int)(Math.random() * 9);

            System.out.println("What is " + op1 + "+" + op2 + "?");
            studentAnswer = input.nextInt();

            if(studentAnswer == op1 + op2){
                System.out.println(studentAnswer + " is correct");
                numCorrect++;
            }else{
                System.out.println(studentAnswer + " is wrong. The right answer is " + (op1 + op2));
            }
            problemCount++;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is my first post sorry for the formatting, what I have done is that i added a static variable that is the number of questions you want the user to be asked (final int NUM_PROBLEMS = 10;) Your while loop was ending before the if statements for true and false. I fixed that, changed the while to make sure it stops when 10 questions is asked and at the bottom incremented problemCount.

Comment: add explaination of code to your answer. dont add it in comment.